How many $5-$digits numbers, in base $10$, have the digit $2$?
How many $5-$digits numbers, in base $10$, have the digit $2$?
Dear all, I tried it like this:
$8*9*9*9*1*5 = 29160 $  (i.e., a number different from two and zero*a number different from two$\times$a number different from two$\times$a number different from two$\times$the number two$\times$five (because number two can occupy five different positions))
Similarly, I continued the reasoning and did:
8$\times$9$\times$9$\times$1$\times$1$\times$10=6480
8$\times$9$\times$1$\times$1$\times$1$\times$10=720
8$\times$1$\times$1$\times$1$\times$1$\times$5=40
1$\times$1$\times$1$\times$1$\times$1=1
However, the answer is $37512$ and I am calculating $36321$. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Easier to count those without a $2$.

If you don't want to use complement (this method is long)
First:
Total of $5$ digit numbers containing one $2$ is: $9^4+(8*9^3)*4=29889$
Note:
$9^{4}*\binom{4}{0}=9^{4}*1$ counts $2x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}$.
$(8*9^{3})*\binom{4}{1}=(8*9^{3})*4$ counts $x_{1}2 x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}$, $x_{1}x_{2}2x_{3}x_{4}$, $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}2x_{4}$, and $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}2$.
Second:
Total of $5$ digit numbers containing two $2s$ is:$(9^{3})*\binom{4}{1}+(8*9^{2})*\binom{4}{2}=6804$
Note:
$(9^{3})*\binom{4}{1}=(9^{3})*4 $ counts $22x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}$,$2x_{1}2x_{2}x_{3}$, $2x_{1}x_{2}2x_{3}$, and $2x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}2$
$(8*9^{2})*\binom{4}{2}=(8*9^{2})*3$ counts $x_{1}22x_{2}x_{3}$,$x_{1}2x_{2}2x_{3}$, $x_{1}2x_{2}x_{3}2$,$x_{1}x_{2}22x_{3}$,$x_{1}x_{2}2x_{3}2$, and $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}22$
Third:
Total of $5$ digit numbers containing three $2s$ is: $(9^{2})*\binom{4}{2}+(8*9)*\binom{4}{3}=774$
Note:
$(9^{2})*\binom{4}{2}$ counts $222x_{1}x_{2}$,$22x_{1}2x_{2}$, $22x_{1}x_{2}2$, $2x_{1}22x_{2}$, $2x_{1}2x_{2}2$, and $2x_{1}x_{2}22$
$(8*9)*\binom{4}{3}$ counts $x_{1}222x_{2}$, $x_{1}22x_{2}2$, $x_{1}2x_{2}22$, and $x_{1}x_{2}222$
Fourth:
Total of $5$ digit numbers containing four $2s$ is: $9*\binom{4}{3}+8*\binom{4}{4}=44$
Note:
$9*\binom{4}{3}$ counts $2222x_{1}$,$222x_{1}2$,$22x_{1}22$, and $2x_{1}222$
$8*\binom{4}{4}=44$ counts $x_{1}2222$
Fifth:
Total of $5$ digit numbers containing five $2s$ is: $\binom{4}{4}=1$.
Note:
$1$ counts $22222$.
So the total is:
$29889+6804+774+44+1=37512$

The number of $5$-digit numbers is $9\times 10^4=90000$
The number of $5$-digit numbers not including $2$ is $8\times 9^4=52488$
$9\times 10^4 - 8\times 9^4 = 37512$

The subtractive approach provided in other answers is the easiest. A direct approach yields
$$n=\sum_{k=1}^4 8 {4 \choose k} 9^{4-k} +
\sum_{k=0}^4 {4 \choose k} 9^{4-k}
,$$
where $k$ is the number of 2’s not in the most-significant (i.e., ten thousands) place. The first sum counts the numbers where the most-significant place doesn’t contain a 2, and the second counts the numbers where it does.
Computing the two sums yields
\begin{align*}
  n&=27512 + 10000\\
   &=37512 .
\end{align*}

Calculate the number of 5-digit numbers that do not have the digit 2 in them. This is $8 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 \times 9 = 52488$.
The total number of 5-digit numbers are the numbers 10000 to 99999 inclusive which is 90000.
So the total number of 5-digit numbers with at least one of the digits being 2 is $90000-52488 = 37512$

Lion Heart answered before you and both of  you have the same solution, so it is better to delete this solution.
